# CPython: лучший кроссплатформенный GUI

Tags: python, gui

Какая технология для разработки кроссплатформенного графического интерфейса для прикладного ПО есть лучшей и почему? Интересует именно Ваше субъективное мнение. Речь идет про язык программирования Python традиционной С-реализации.

Comment: @uzumaxy

    Крошка сын пришёл к отцу
    И спросила кроха:
    -- Что такое хорошо
    И что такое плохо?

Критерии-то какие?

Comment: Может это немного странно, но для меня не важен какой-то конкретный критерий. В данный момент не стоит никаких задач по разработке с использованием этой технологии. Учить буду чисто для себя, но время зря тратить не желаю. Хочется выбрать оптимальный по всем параметрам GUI Framework.

Comment: @uzumaxy ну так расслабьтесь. Ваша задача существенно упрощается. Такого фреймворка не существует.

Comment: Почему же не существует? Если есть множество технологий, тогда среди них есть лучшие и есть те, что похуже.

Взять, к примеру, .NET с его WPF & Windows Forms. Никто ведь не будет утверждать, что WPF хуже за WF?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Qt/PyQt

Есть ещё какой-то порт. Вообще, само название Qt уже говорит само за себя и объяснять, почему это лучший GUI-framework считаю излишним.

Comment: Как Я понимаю, есть две реализации QT для Python: PyQT и PySide. Вторая — opensource и поддерживается комьюнити. Не имеет значение что использовать?

Comment: Молодо-зелено. А что Вы имеете против Tkinter? А вообще, смотрите мой комментарий к вопросу -- что значит "лучший"?

Comment: Ну функционал-то у PyQt/PySide побольше будет, чем у Tkinter'a. Если не охота ни с чем заморачиваться, то и Tkiter сойдёт. Если охота написать "самое красивое оконное приложение", то тогда PySide. Лично я сначала бы занялся выработкой требований для программы, а уже потом думал об инструментах.

Comment: Когда-то давно кто-то (кажется Москаль) написал, что для создания среднего гуя tcl/tk -- наилучший вариант. А гуи выше среднего -- удовольствие весьма доргое. (За точность цитаты не ручаюсь. Но qt тогда уже было. Вроде бы. Ещё от trolltech)

Comment: @alexlz, чем tcl/tk лучше за pyqt/pyside? Буду рад узнать новую для себя информацию, с пайтоном недавно работаю.

Comment: Главный его плюс -- уже есть в коробке и не надо париться с установкой. В той же коробке есть довольно богатый выбор расширений, так что, если не заморачиваться со всякими drag-and-drop, то можно очень удобный интерфес спроектировать, а для недостающих фиджетов свои костыли написать (или  Возможно, даже выше среднего и быстрее, чем с Qt. Не помню только, можно ли там менять оформление.

Comment: @Montreal, благодарю!

Comment: @uzumaxy увы. Не знаю я Qt, поэтому на данный вопрос ответить не смогу. Правда, что касается tcl/tk, то в его портах есть неприятная особенность -- время от времени ответ на вопрос приходится искать не в мануле на порт, а в мануале на tcl/tk.

Answer (score 3):

мне кажется, Qt, т.к. очень большой список поддерживаемых платформ и возможность нативно выглядеть почти что на каждой из них

Comment: Мне нравится слово "нативно". Native -- туземный, аборигенный. Так и представляется гуёвая программа в обрамлении петушиных перьев.

Comment: native {прилаг.}
родной [родно́й] {прилаг.}

native {прилаг.} (также: natural, unschooled, unstudied, the course of nature)
естественный [есте́ственный] {прилаг.}

Comment: @actionless была у микропрозы (создатель "Цивилизации") когда-то игра "Колонизация". Так там индейцы в переговорах назывались "Native". Так что нативная программа -- это программа в уборе Чингачгука.

Мюллер7:

2> туземный; местный; native customs местные обычаи; to go native перенять обычаи и образ жизни туземцев (о европейцах)

6> _биол. аборигенный

Comment: может, когда-нибудь узнаешь, что такое контекст, не вижу смысла продолжать.

Comment: @actionless, когда-нибудь узнаешь что такое ирония, сарказм и легкий троллинг)

лично меня позабавил комментарий))